# BigQuery: Using a declared variable (checkpoint) with nested select on a partitioned table: getting filter error

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to declare a checkpoint for a partitioned table using a select statement (from another table) but I keep getting an error:

*Query error: Cannot query over table 'xxxxxx' without a filter over column(s) 'timestamp' that can be used for partition elimination at [5:1]*

I've simplified this as much as possible to demonstrate it. Here is an example  partitioned table declaration:

```
create table xxx.xxx.partitioned_table 
PARTITION BY date(timestamp)
OPTIONS (require_partition_filter = TRUE)
as (
  select 
    1 as id, 
    "one" as name, 
    "1" as string_value, 
    timestamp_add(current_timestamp(), interval -4 day) as timestamp 
  union all
  select 2, "two", "2", timestamp_add(current_timestamp(), interval -3 day) union all
  select 3, "three", "3", timestamp_add(current_timestamp(), interval -2 day) union all
  select 4, "four", "4", timestamp_add(current_timestamp(), interval -1 day) union all
  select 5, "five" "5", current_timestamp()
) ;
```

Now, I declare the checkpoint and attempt to use it:

```
declare timestamp_checkpoint default (
  select timestamp_add(current_timestamp(), interval -2 day)
);
  
SELECT *
FROM `xxx.xxx.partitioned_table` 
WHERE timestamp > timestamp_checkpoint
AND id > 3
```

The above fails.

However the below works (only the timestamp in the where clause), although it gives a warning "WARNING: Could not compute bytes processed estimate for script."

```
declare timestamp_checkpoint default (
  select timestamp_add(current_timestamp(), interval -2 day)
);
  
SELECT *
FROM `xxx.xxx.partitioned_table` 
WHERE timestamp > timestamp_checkpoint
```

The below ALSO works, AND gives the size estimate for the script:

```
declare timestamp_checkpoint default (
  timestamp_add(current_timestamp(), interval -2 day)
);
  
SELECT *
FROM `xxx.xxx.partitioned_table` 
WHERE timestamp > timestamp_checkpoint
AND id > 3
```

In my real script, I want to select from another table entirely, so unfortunately I can't just hard-code the dates.

I'm sure this is something simple. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug with `require_partition_filter`. However, this can be fooled by adding another date restriction. If added `date(timestamp)>"1970-01-01"` the BigQuery check for filtering is fulfilled. The addition date filtering is still active and reduces the amount billed. Please check this again for your use case.

Generate a larger table.

```sql
create or replace table xxx.xxx.partitioned_table
PARTITION BY date(timestamp)
OPTIONS (require_partition_filter = TRUE)
as (
  select 
     id, 
    "one" as name, 
    "1" as string_value, 
    timestamp_add(current_timestamp(), interval -4 day) as timestamp,
    from unnest(generate_array(1,1000*1000)) id
  union all
  select 2, "two", "2", timestamp_add(current_timestamp(), interval -3 day) union all
  select 3, "three", "3", timestamp_add(current_timestamp(), interval -2 day) union all
  select 4, "four", "4", timestamp_add(current_timestamp(), interval -1 day) union all
  select 5, "five", "5", current_timestamp()
) ;
```

And now the working query:

```
declare timestamp_checkpoint default (
  timestamp_add(current_timestamp(), interval -2 day)
);
  
SELECT *
FROM xxx.xxx.partitioned_table
WHERE timestamp > timestamp_checkpoint
AND id > 3 and date(timestamp)>"1970-01-01"
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That workaround is a charm. I'll see about reporting this to GCP.

Comment: This seems to have been reported here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/273229654

Please visit and +1 if you also are affected by this issue